# Android > Is there a list of certified devices with details as Biometric device strength?

Tags: android, validation, security, testing, biometrics

Is there anywhere a list of devices that have passed Android certification with information about the strength of their biometric sensor?

As per [google's docs](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure), biometric sensors are classified as Class 3 ("Strong"), Class 2 ("Convenience") or Class 1 ("Weak") depending on their performance/capabilities. But I'd like to know if there's some list anywhere reflecting that device XYZ has passed certification with a Class 3 or Class 2 sensor or whatever.

Source: [Measuring Biometric Unlock Security  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure)